# is there Chainway c72 UHF Rfid Reader Mobile application Flutter or ReactNative package?

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, rfid

I have a C72 Chainway UHF reader and I'm trying to develop a custom application
is there any package supported Flutter development environment or react Native or anyway!! :/  to handle scanning RFID tags ?

simple code handle chainway c72 reading and scanning tags or any package support that

Answer (score 0):

On pub.dev there is a package called uhf_c72_plugin 1.0.1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturer only has implementations for Android Studio and Xamarin here https://www.chainway.net/Support/Info/10. I have implemented Apps on Java and Kotlin using Chainway official SDK version 20230302, you can implement your app using handlers and also you can use flow on Kotlin. I haven't done much on Flutter, but one easy way to get tag reads on your Flutter app is using a preinstalled app that comes with the device, which helps to get tag reads as a keyboard emulator (wedge mode), so you just need to set the focus on a text box or text area that supports multiple lines, and whatever the reader reads, it will be inserted on the control, you can configure the read functionality with any physical buttons on the device or the gun that comes with it. I hope this may help.